# Can't decode Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping

I have the following code

```
results = requests.get("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/ano64pm6?apikey=9ummN7C6KMHu9aErm49ixoy2ZySmaKCm").json()
mmoga = ([x["price"] for x in results["results"]["collection1"]])
print mmoga
```

This outputs the following:

```
[u'\xa3\xa04.03', u'\xa3\xa06.02', u'\xa3\xa07.99', u'\xa3\xa09.96', u'\xa
\xa011.91', u'\xa3\xa013.84', u'\xa3\xa015.76', u'\xa3\xa017.67', u'\xa
\xa019.56', u'\xa3\xa029.24', u'\xa3\xa038.84', u'\xa3\xa048.38', u'\xa
\xa057.84', u'\xa3\xa067.23', u'\xa3\xa076.56', u'\xa3\xa085.81', u'\xa
\xa094.99', u'\xa3\xa0113.57', u'\xa3\xa0132.00', u'\xa3\xa0150.29',u'\xa3
\xa0168.45', u'\xa3\xa0186.46', u'\xa3\xa0204.33', u'\xa3  \xa0222.06',
u'\xa3    \xa0239.65', u'\xa3\xa0257.10', u'\xa3\xa0274.43']
[u'\xa3\xa04.03', u'\xa3\xa06.02', u'\xa3\xa07.99', u'\xa3\xa09.96', u'\xa  
\xa011.91', u'\xa3\xa013.84', u'\xa3\xa015.76', u'\xa3\xa017.67', u'\xa3    
\xa019.56', u'\xa3\xa029.24', u'\xa3\xa038.84', u'\xa3\xa048.38', u'\xa3
\xa057.84', u'\xa3\xa067.23', u'\xa3\xa076.56', u'\xa3\xa085.81', u'\xa3
\xa094.99', u'\xa3\xa0113.57', u'\xa3\xa0132.00', u'\xa3\xa0150.29', u'\xa3
\xa0168.45', u'\xa3\xa0186.46', u'\xa3\xa0204.33', u'\xa3\xa0222.06', u'\xa3
\xa0239.65', u'\xa3\xa0257.10', u'\xa3\xa0274.43']
```

I then try to get rid of all the letters using the following code:

```
while i< len(mmoga):
mmoga[i] = mmoga[i].translate(None, 'absdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz;&£$')
i+=1
```

This gives the error message

```
 translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

From some searching I think that that this is due to the Unicode not being decoded but I am very new to Python and all the solutions I have found are in Python 3.

Comment: Why don't you use Python3? Where's the minimal example code?

Comment: I have quite a large web scraping program written scraping other sites so would have to convert it all to Python 3 which would take me a considerable amount of time as I am fairly new to Python

Comment: @Ulrich: why would Python 3 make this task easier? The only significant difference would be that representations would show the Unicode glyph rather than the escape sequence here but it won't help understanding of what is actually happening.

Comment: The reason is that "all the solutions I have found are in Python 3", @MartijnPieters. I wanted to point out that there is little reason to start with Python 2. Inheriting an existing project is different though.

Answer (score 2):

You successfully decoded the contents, but the `\xa3` and `\xa0` characters may be confusing you. These are simply the [U+00A3 POUND SIGN](http://codepoints.net/U+00A3) and [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00A0) characters, but Python only includes ASCII characters in unicode string representations, the rest are shown as escape sequences here.

Print one of those values individually:

```
>>> print u'\xa3\xa04.03'
£ 4.03
```

The `unicode.translate()` method works differently from the `str.translate`. To delete characters, put them in the first argument as a dictionary mapping to `None`.

I'd use `str.strip()` here:

```
>>> u'\xa3\xa04.03'.strip(u'\xa3\xa0')
u'4.03'
```